# Keras custom loss function not printing value of tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am writing just a simple loss function in which I have to convert the tensor to numpy array(it's essential). I am just trying to print value of the tensor but I am getting this error:-

> Tensor("loss/activation_4_loss/Print:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 2),
>   dtype=float32)

```
def Lc(y_true, y_pred):
    x=K.print_tensor(y_pred)
    print(x)
    return K.mean(y_pred)
```

Kindly tell me that how can I get the value(numerics) from the tensor? I also tried "eval" but it also threw a big fat error about no session is there and it is a placeholder etc. The whole program is executing fine, just "*print_tensor*" line is causing problem.

Comment: The `K.print_tensor()` seems to return a Print Tensor object. Simply follow the basic steps : `print( tf.Session().run(x) )`

Comment: Also, if necessary, you can enable the eager mode in TensorFlow so that the values of Tensors are printed.

Comment: Your premise is wrong, no loss function in Keras will work if you use numpy as part of it, because there is no way to propagate gradients through numpy code.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal I am getting error of you must feed value, when doing tf.session().run(x) in the keras custom loss.

Answer (score 3):

The print statement is redundant. print_tensor will already print the values.

From the documentation of print_tensor:

"Note that `print_tensor` returns a new tensor identical to `x`
     **which should be used in the following code. Otherwise the
     print operation is not taken into account during evaluation**."

In the code above, since y_pred was assigned to x and x was no longer used, the print failed.

Use the version below.

```
def Lc(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred=K.print_tensor(y_pred)
    return K.mean(y_pred)
```

---

```
def cat_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.print_tensor(y_pred)
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

After I put this cat_loss function in my training loop, I can see the output like this:

[[0.000191014129 0.230871275 0.43813318]...]

190/255 [=====================>........] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3442 - acc: 0.9015

[[3.16367514e-05 1.70419597e-07 0.000147014405]...]